# Wrong font in qpdfview

Tags: fonts

Some pdf file open like figure below (text is hard to read). The text is most probably writen in times-font. How to add font to qpdfview. Thank You for advice
[text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyo41.png)

Comment: I do not understand your question. The inherent function of a pdf viewer is to show a document as the author has created it. Changing fonts would render the formatting different - something a "document preserving reader" should not do

Answer (score 2):

Fonts, the entire font set or a subset, may be embedded in the PDF file, and are then used by the PDF viewer to display the text. If fonts are not embedded, the font installed on the system is used. If not installed on the system, a substitute font is used, eventually leading to suboptimal rendering.

Many fonts used in commercial printing (that includes PDF files) are unfree. That means you may or may not be able to purchase them to install them on your computer. If you can, a PDF where that proprietary font is used, but not embedded in the file, will be displayed correctly.